# Parsing remote csv file : No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby, csv, rails-activestorage

I am trying to parse a csv file hosted remotely. I user rails 6 and active storage. The file is stored on the ImportJob model. Its url can be accessed this way :

```
ImportJob.last.csv_file.url
```

the file does exist and is downloadable : http://res.cloudinary.com/dockcyr0z/raw/upload/rghn3zi2190nmc28qwbtr24apqxe.csv

However when trying to parse it

```
CSV.foreach(url, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol, col_sep: ';') do |row|
 puts row
end
```

Im getting `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - http://res.cloudinary.com/dockcyr0z/raw/upload/rghn3zi2190nmc28qwbtr24apqxe.csv`

same thing if I try to open the file first : `open(url)`

Why am I getting this error ? How can I parse this remote csv file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `url` with `URI.parse` and change `CSV.foreach` to `CSV.parse`

```rb
CSV.parse(URI.parse(url).read, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol, col_sep: ';') do |row|
  puts row
end
```

```rb
# output

{
    :first_name => "Souper",
     :last_name => "Man",
         :email => "dageismar+learner233@gmail.com",
          :role => "CEO",
          :tags => "sales,marketing",
    :avatar_url => "http://res.cloudinary.com/dockcyr0z/image/upload/x3f65o5mepbdhi4fwvww99gjqr7p"
}
{
    :first_name => "Gentil",
     :last_name => "Keum",
         :email => "dageismar+learner234@gmail.com",
          :role => "CEO",
          :tags => "sales,marketing",
    :avatar_url => "http://res.cloudinary.com/dockcyr0z/image/upload/x3f65o5mepbdhi4fwvww99gjqr7p"
}
```

**Update**:

Or as [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477037/stefan) suggests just `URI.open(url)` instead of `URI.parse(url).read`

Comment: Also works with `CSV.parse(URI.open(url), ...)` from [`OpenURI`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html)

Comment: Good catch. Thanks)